# paintComponent(g) or paintComponent(g2)?

Tags: java, graphics, paint

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.fillRect(0,0,25,25);
}
```

OR

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paintComponent(g2);
    g2.fillRect(0,0,25,25);
}
```

Which would be correct if I was using Graphics2D? Would I still paintComponent(g) or pass that to g2 instead?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I would use the second one but I just want to know which would be the correct way in case I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: If `g` is actually a `Graphics2D` (and I don't see AWT coming back), then these are **literally** the same.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. It's the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Graphics` is an abstract class, and as such cannot be instantiated. Given that `Graphics` has only two implementations in the native Java library, `Graphics2D` and `DebugGraphics`, you can assume that `g` will be `Graphics2D`, making the second method rather redundant (but not incorrect). `DebugGraphics` is rarely used to draw graphics by hand.

To summarize, you can pass it in either way, because they are 100% equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

The method `paintComponent` accepts `Graphics` as parameter, and `Graphics2D` is a sub-class of `Graphics`. So, passing `g` to `super.paintComponent` is equivalent to passing `g2`. It would be different, though, if `super.paintComponent` is overloaded so that one version accepts `Graphics` and another version accepts `Graphics2D` (which is not the case here).